# Prevent script running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I using  next JS for adding class by click on element and removing it by clicking outside of element:

```
$(function() {
  $('.main').mousedown(function() {
    return $(this).find('.drop').addClass("dropped", 300);
  });
  $('.main').click(function(event) {
    return event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    return $('.drop').removeClass("dropped");
  });

});
```

The html structure is:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="drop">Click Here</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="drop">Click Here</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="drop">Click Here</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="drop">Click Here</div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSfiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/CWJrn/)

As you can see i using `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent `removeClass` by clicking on same element. But it prevents clicking by all `main` divs. How make it to prevent only for clicked `main` div, means if all `main` divs are clicked and then i click in some of them then the rest are accepted `.removeClass("dropped");` exclude the clicked one.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3NJtu/1/ ?

Comment: There's no need for the `return` in any of those functions.

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3NJtu/3/

Comment: Also, addClass() doesn't take a time parameter.

Comment: @j08691 i guess OP is using jquery UI on real site

Comment: @ArunPJohny it not works because if we add another element in main div and click on it the `.removeClass` action is not prevented http://jsfiddle.net/3NJtu/5/

Comment: @Dmitry see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3NJtu/6/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks! Seems this on works as needed :)

Comment: @Dmitry I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('.main').mousedown(function () {
        return $(this).find('.drop').addClass("dropped", 300);
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        return $('.drop.dropped').not($(e.target).closest('.main').find('.drop')).removeClass("dropped");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3NJtu/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it fits your need, but try:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWJrn/7/)

```
$('.main').attr('tabindex', -1).css('outline', 'none');

$(document).on('focus blur', '.main', function () {
    $(this).find('.drop').toggleClass('dropped');
});
```